# Why does a wooden spoon creates bubbles when put in hot oil?

Tags: thermodynamics, boiling-point

This question might be a bit weird, but I just asked myself why a wooden cooking spoon creates bubbles when put in oil at about 170°C. This is a common trick to find out, if Oil has the right temperature for frying.
My idea is, that the water in the wooden spoon starts to evaporate, but why does this just start to happen when the Oil reaches approx 170°C? Why does this not happen at 100 or 120°C ?

Comment: No specific reason. At 220, the bubbles become very strong. At 120, you barely see them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my hypothesis that the bubbles are created due to the evaporation of water is true?

Comment: It may not be just free water evaporation, but also cellulose dehydration or even starting overall wood pyrolysis.

Comment: @Poutnik Wood pyrolysis seems unconvincing. I think cellulose dehydration is a better probability.

Comment: @desai Well, try to let organic material in an oven at 170 deg C for longer time. It may be slow, but... The famous novel 451deg F means 232 deg C.